# How can I get FlashVars values in ActionScript 2.0?

Tags: xml, flash, query-string, flashvars

I have to dynamically send a flashvars value from `<object>/<embed>`, for example `"<object name="flashvars" value="test=myxml.xml">` to my swf file.

And in my AS, I have this:

```
var xmlPath:String = _level0.test;
doc.load(xmlPath);
```

So, this way I want to read several xml files (at least it's my intention!). 
But nothing of what I do works...

I also tried

```
doc.load(_root.test)
```

but it didnt work too.

If I do:

```
doc.load("someXML.xml")
```

It works just fine!!

I'm trying to solve this for many many hours and still didn't find any solution!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your HTML markup:

For an `<object>` tag you need to use a param tag within it, e.g.

```
<object ...>
<param name="FlashVars" value="test=myxml.xml">
</object>
```

For an `<embed>` tag, its an attribute of the tag

```
<embed FlashVars="test=myxml.xml" ...>
```

Here's an [Adobe TechNote on using FlashVars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) which might help you too.

Comment: If your html is correct, then why do you mention an embed tag in 2009?
 Mind the Capitals in Paul's post! The result truly is different.

Answer (score 0):

xhtml/html5:

```
<param name="FlashVars" value="flvurl=coolmovie" />
```

AS2:

```
myFLV.source = "http://www.dom.tld/flv/"+root.loaderInfo.parameters.flvurl+".flv";
```